# Can I use web3 with Ethereum Classic?

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereum-classic

I just learnt using web3 to interact with Ethereum.

1. Is there a similar library to web3 to work with Ethereum Classic?
2. Is there a testnet faucet?
3. Does it work with Parity?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need a similar library, web3 (js or python or anything else) can be used with ETC. Ethereum and Ethereum Classic nodes share the same JSON-RPC API. Here's a [tutorial](https://engineeringterminal.com/cryptocurrency-and-blockchain/tutorials/connecting-to-ethereum-networks-with-web3js.html).
2. Sure, there's this [ETC Testnet faucet](https://testnet.epool.io) for the former Morden testnet (dully called now "The Testnet").
3. Of course! Just run `parity --chain classic`. Run `parity --help` for more info.

As an important side note, there's a recent movement to spin up a cross-client PoA testnet which will be compatible with most of, if not all, the Ethereum clients out there (geth-eth, geth-etc, parity etc). It is called Goerli and you can read more about it in this [article](https://medium.com/ethereum-classic/building-a-better-unified-testnet-3f48490cd4e1).